# Can I change the component using ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush in Angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-changedetection

I was referring to memory leaks and I got to know about `ChangeDetectionStrategy`. I got really nice [blog](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html) . I am trying this in my project. Now the issue is as this detects changes in `Input` but what if component is getting changed. Will it be able to render it ? Any demo regarding it should be appreciable if it is possible then.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `OnPush` and when you run into a concrete problem, then ask a question about it. You can always inject `ChangeDetectorRef` and call `markForCheck()` if you modified the model by means that doesn't invoke change detection by default.

Comment: I already did that. But what happens that When I am loading new component that time I am still getting old component's screen.

Comment: No idea what you mean. Please post the code or even better a Plunker that allows to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I am sorry for my bad English. But as my code it too complex I was just looking for common solution whether it is possible or not.

Comment: I have dynamic tabs in my project. If i click anything in menu it opens in new tab. So when I am trying to open tab I am only getting data of previous tab which was loaded initially. So the component is not getting changed. May be this might help to understand.

Comment: Please show the code. Your explanation doesn't provide enough information.

Comment: Ok let me try to provide the plunkr

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure you implement the ChangeDetectionStrategy and reference the renderer. By using renderer.listen and changing the detector to markForCheck() the view will also update to the correct state.

```
    @Component({
    selector: 'test',
    template: `
<div class="a-input">
  <div class="a-input__checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" [id]="id" name="{{id}}" [(ngModel)]="checked" [disabled]="disabled">
    <label for="{{id}}"></label>
  </div>
</div>
    `,
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class TableCheckboxComponent implements CellComponent {
    @Input() data;
    @Input() id: number;
    @Input() checked: boolean = false;
    @Input() disabled: boolean = false;

    @Output() stateChanged: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

    constructor(private changeDetector: ChangeDetectorRef, elementRef: ElementRef, renderer: Renderer) {
        // Listen to click events in the component
        renderer.listen(elementRef.nativeElement, 'click', (event) => {
            if (!this.disabled) {
                this.checkedChange();
                this.changeDetector.markForCheck();
            }
        });
    }

    checkedChange(): void {
        this.checked = !this.checked;
        this.stateChanged.emit(/* send object id and status here */);
    }
}
```